# What startTime on React's Profiler API means?

Tags: reactjs, profiler

I'm studying the React's Profiler API and while reading the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html#onrender-callback) and [@bvaughn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1123805/bvaughn) [note](https://gist.github.com/bvaughn/60a883af01716a03a1b3285a1029be0c#start-and-commit-times), I got confused about what exactly the `startTime` is measuring.

[image]

It refers to (a) the time before the render phase begins or (b) the time before the commit phase begins or (c) none?

Answer (score 0):

When a DOM changes, React rerendering the DOM. The `startTime` is the timestamp when React began rendering the current update. In fact, `startTime` is the time the Profiler started measuring the mount/render time for its descendants.